# WSO2 API Manager set old TLS version for one API

Tags: ssl, wso2

I'm using API manager v4.1.0 and my TLS configuration is

```
[transport.passthru_https.listener.parameters]
HttpsProtocols = "TLSv1.3"
```

Is it possible to enable the older version of TLS for only one API?

Answer (score 0):

sorry but this is not possible as it need to be setup at the transport level and as the same transport is shared between apis.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).